# Trying to use Canvas and DrawImage to display low-rate video at 90 degrees

Tags: html, video, canvas, rotation, drawimage

I would like to display rotated camera video at a rate of 2 frames/second.  The following code displays a 240 x 320 image rotated at 90 degrees.  The image does not update unless I refresh the browser.  The source that is changing is cam_1.jpg.  It seems that once DrawImage has a src image, it does look for an update.

What have I not learned yet?  Thank You for your time and expertise.

```
<title>CamDisplay</title></head><body>
<canvas height="320" width="240"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var cam = new Image;
    window.onload = function(){
        var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        setInterval(function(){
            ctx.save();
            ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 240, 320 );
            ctx.translate( 240, 0);

            cam.src = 'cam_1.jpg?uniq='+Math.random();

            ctx.rotate( 1.57);
            ctx.drawImage( cam, 0, 0 );
                            ctx.restore();
        },500);
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image is not getting time to load. try

```
var cam = new Image;
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

cam.onload = function() {
        ctx.save();
         ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 240, 320 );
         ctx.translate( 240, 0);
         ctx.rotate( 1.57);
         ctx.drawImage( this, 0, 0 );
        ctx.restore();  
    }

window.onload = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        cam.src = 'cam_1.jpg?uniq='+Math.random();
    },500);
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! I've been working on this for a week. I guess what you did was to move the cam.src assignment outside of the loop to draw so as to give the new frame time to load before attempting to display it. Perhaps you have a more accurate description.  Thank you for your time and expertise!  Works perfectly.  Frank