# Using Canvas and Drawimage in functions with video

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video-streaming, drawimage

I am using the HTML5 canvas and DrawImage functions to display low rate video.  tnt gave excellent advice to get this project off the ground: [Trying to use Canvas and DrawImage to display low-rate video at 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138617/trying-to-use-canvas-and-drawimage-to-display-low-rate-video-at-90-degrees)

While tnt's solution worked fine when the camera and angle are known at load time by using onload functions, I need to be able to turn the video off and on between several cameras  and change other parameters.  To handle that, a number of individual functions are needed, but I haven't been able to first do a setInterval on a camera and then pass the constantly changing image to DrawImage.  'cam_1.jpg' is the video in the example below.  The functions shown in body onload below will also have to be called by other routines during runtime.  Any advice will be appreciated.

```
var cam = null;
var c = null;
var ctx = null;
var ra = 0;

function init() {
cam = new Image;
c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
ctx = c.getContext('2d');
}
 function draw(cam) {
       ctx.save();
       ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 240, 320 );
       ctx.translate( 240, 0);
       ctx.rotate(1.57);
       ctx.drawImage(cam, 0, 0 );
       ctx.restore();
       }

function inter() {
setInterval(function(){cam.src = 'cam_1.jpg?uniq='+Math.random();},500);
}

</script></head><body onload = "init(),  draw(cam), inter()" >
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an object array; something like this:

```
var cams = []; // an array to hold you cams!

function addcam() {
  this.image = new Image;
  this.setting1 = 0;
  this.settingn = 0;
}  

cams[1] = addcam();
cams[1].image.src = "cam1.jpg";
cams[1].setting1 = 2;

setInterval(function(){cam.src = '+cams[1].image.src+'?uniq='+Math.random();},500);
```

Answer (score 1):

@tnt, Are you suggesting the following?  Thank you:

```
var cams = []; // an array to hold you cams!  

function addcam() {
  this.image = new Image;
  this.setting1 = 0;
  this.settingn = 0;
}

function draw(camnum){
cams[1] = addcam();
cams[1].image.src = "cam_1.jpg";
cams[1].setting1 = 2;
cam = new Image;
c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
ctx = c.getContext('2d');
}

function inter() {
setInterval(function(){'cam.src = ' +cams[1].image.src+ '?uniq='+Math.random();},500);
}  

function draw(cam) {
       ctx.save();
       ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 240, 320 );
       ctx.translate( 240, 0);
       ctx.rotate( 1.57);
       ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0 );
       ctx.restore();
}

</script></head><body onload = "draw(cam), inter()" >
```